# is there way to define schema while reading from mongo document in python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pyspark, etl, google-cloud-data-fusion

I working on some ETL flow which reads data from Mongo DB using Google Data fusion. While the data is read from the source, we are facing issues with missing key fields in the document, as the source is inconsistent with key across the documents inside the collection. I'm just looking for a way, to define a schema while reading and the program should return null value when the key is absent inside the document.

Not sure whether it is duplicate question, but need some help around this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: look at this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#mongodb-query-op.-jsonSchema

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It is more towards validations. However, just wanted to know if we can do with pymongo to auto return null to the missing keys , which keys I defined that needs to be available.

Comment: I can imagine only finding documents that don't match to the schema in the first aggregation stage and then updating the result via manual changes like in $project stage